# NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path error after change View As -> "Enable Size Classes.."

Tags: ios, xamarin

After I selected View As -> "Enable Size Classes.." option in the designer UI, I cannot run the project anymore. I am getting this error. Any idea how to fix this ?

> MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.
>   Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: There doesn't seem to be a
>   valid compiled storyboard at path
>   '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/FF1A6941-B237-41E5-9463-F6E3252A21CB/xbmc_music.app/MainStoryboard.storyboardc'
>   at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowNSException (IntPtr
>   ns_exception) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1799/3c4e832a/source/maccore/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:167
>   at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (IntPtr exc)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at (wrapper native-to-managed)
>   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime:throw_ns_exception (intptr)   at
>   (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain
>   (int,string[],intptr,intptr)   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main
>   (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1799/3c4e832a/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
>   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args,
>   System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName)
>   [0x0001c] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1799/3c4e832a/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:46
>   at xbmc_music.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00035] in
>   /Users/Apple/Projects/xoxo/xbmc_music/xbmc_music/Main.cs:46 
>   NSInvalidArgumentException: There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled
>   storyboard at path
>   '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/FF1A6941-B237-41E5-9463-F6E3252A21CB/xbmc_music.app/MainStoryboard.